# Sharing a list of files containing spaces in multiple scripts

Tags: arrays, bash, environment

I have a list of a number of filenames (containing spaces) which I want to use in multiple scripts.

script1:
myprog.py ***my favourite files***

script2:
for f in ***my favourite files***

I have tried using an environment variable but that fails due to the spaces.
How can I do this?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Does `my favourite files` represent a file, several files, or a file that contains your list of filenames.

Comment: Start by reading http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashProgramming

Comment: @Lorccan it represents a list of filenames contained in some object which can be accessed from multiple scripts. It is not a file. In other languages it could be an 'include' or a macro.

Comment: Is this list of files a list of double quoted filenames ? single quoted filenames ? unquoted filenames with escaped spaces ?

Comment: @Zilog80 I'm easy, you decide which format and I'll use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume a file that has your list in it.

```
$: cat lst
this file.txt
my favorite.csv
that other.mpg
```

For simplicity, here's my version of one of your programs.

```
$: cat script1
for f in "$@"; do echo "$f"; done
```

So if I understand you correctly, you are calling it this way, and getting this sort of wrong result:

```
$: ./script1 this file.txt my favorite.csv that other.mpg
this
file.txt
my
favorite.csv
that
other.mpg
```

First, read up on proper quoting.

```
$: ./script1 "this file.txt" "my favorite.csv" "that other.mpg"
this file.txt
my favorite.csv
that other.mpg
```

and try using arrays.

```
$: mapfile -t ary < ./lst
$: ./script1 "${ary[@]}"
this file.txt
my favorite.csv
that other.mpg
```

This works inside the script too. Try just passing name of the file that has the list, and let your program read it.

Comment: Super, the mapfile was what I was missing. I'd tried using read, but couldn't get it to work as I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: `mapfile`... Yet another small nifty thing provided by Linux I didn't know about :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

python `foo.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys 

for f in sys.argv:
    print(f)
```

bash:

```
foo=("my favorite" "files")
./foo.py "${foo[@]}"
```

output:

```
./foo.py
my favorite
files
```

PS: Search for "bash arrays" using your favorite internet search engine

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It doesn't actually answer my question though.

Comment: It actually does, just not with much clarity.